# float property for inline element

Tags: html, css, css-float

Can we apply float property to inline element? if we could, is there any difference between a floated inline-box and a floated block-box, like this two elements:

```
<span style="float: left;">hello</span>
<span style="float: left; display: block;">hello</span>
```

thank you!

Comment: You should read [this](http://learnlayout.com/display.html) to get an idea of how different `display` settings work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with CSS rules, when you apply `float` to an element, in most cases it becomes a block element. Elements that are `inline` and `inline-block` will compute to `block`.

From MDN:

[image]

References:

- [9.7 Relationships between `display`, `position`, and `float`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)
- [`float` definition at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: @Leothelion, I posted my answer. Later, somebody posted a comment suggesting a possible duplicate. The suggestion was valid, so I marked this question as a dupe. The comment was deleted. In short, I was unaware of the dupe when I posted my answer.

Comment: oh..ok. no problem :)